# Entitlements error in xCode 6 iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I am getting this error while trying to use an App Store Provisioning profile:

```
The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements
```

file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

I went into the "capabilities" section in Xcode and they match the app in iTunes connect.

What do I put in my entitlements file, what should it be called, and where should it be located. And how do I import the entitlements into my Xcode project?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into your project settings in xcode, both under Project -> Build Settings and Targets -> Build Settings.  The Provisioning Profile you wish to use should be chosen next to Provisioning Profile
2. In those same locations, look under Code Signing Identity.  Whatever code signing certificate you used when creating that specific Provisioning Profile should be selected.  You are probably selecting a certificate that was not selected in your provisioning profile.
3. If you are running on a device, make sure the device has been added to that Provisioning Profile.